# javascript regular expression from text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression in javascript

```
var re = /\[topswf([^[]*(?:\[(?!topswf\]|\/topswf\])[^[]*)*)\]/ig
```

How can I rewrite this regular expression using regex?
I tried this:

```
var re = new RegExp("/\\[topswf([^[]*(?:\\[(?!topswf\\]|\\/topswf\\])[^[]*)*)\\]/ig")
```

and this:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\[topswf([^[]*(?:\\[(?!topswf\\]|\\/topswf\\])[^[]*)*)\\]/ig')
```

but neither works, How can I rewrite this?

Comment: Read the documentation for the RegExp constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flags for ignore case and global should be passed as second parameter to the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\[topswf([^[]*(?:\\[(?!topswf\\]|\\/topswf\\])[^[]*)*)\\]', 'ig');
```

Comment: Exactly. Thanks Darin for help